# Kafka, control other partition offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic and two consumer groups each consuming that one topic.

One bunch of services consume the topic using consumer group A and the other bunch of services consumer the topic using consumer group B.

Typically consumer group A processes the events much quicker that group B.

I want to prevent the consumers in group A getting too far ahead of the consumers in group B.

Is there a way to do this?

Can I perhaps slow consumption of group A if group B falls too far behind or can I get group B to control the offset of Group A in any way, using Kafka.

(the reason for the slowness in consumer services b is two things, less are provisioned and the back end it uses is slower)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I perhaps slow consumption of group A if group B falls too far behind

If you have access to group B's position, then you can just avoid calling `poll` in group A's consumer until group B catches up (if you are using some kind of thick wrapping like spring-kafka, you might need to stop & re-create your listener).

Depending on how groups are configured regarding saving offsets, the other group can also access group's position by reading from *internal* `__consumer_offsets` topic (you might want to see how `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` from server directory does that).

> can I get group B to control the offset of Group A in any way

Not really. You can write to `__consumer_offsets` to change Group A's offset, but that value would be read only when consumer is re-created, *not* when it is still running. Basically if you want this level of communication, you'd need to write your own code that would make Group-B-service communicate with Group-A-service to change its offset via `seek`.

In general the point is that - if the consumer is already running - then there's no communication, unless you create something.

Comment: Good post thanks, one thing though on your first point, if I avoid calling poll in Group A's consumer could those consumers get kicked out and a re-balance occur? or other adverse side affects when preventing poll getting called?

Comment: Yes, you might want to take a look at `max.poll.interval.ms` property - it controls how long a consumer might not poll.

Comment: Or alternatively (and that's a hack), you can periodically do something like `poll(); seek(previous position); commit(previous position)` so the poll happens, just the data gets rejected - it's not pretty though.